The accuracy of the formula that I created
$$ F = \frac{2RSA}{c} \sin^2 \theta  $$
$$ F = am \ \ ↔ \ \ a = \frac{F}{m} $$
$$ S(r) = \frac{L}{4 \pi r^2c} $$
$$ \begin{align} 
a(r) & = \frac{F(r)}{m} \\ 
 & = \frac{2RS(r)A}{mc} \sin^2 \theta 
\end{align} $$
$$ r' = r_2 - r_1$$
$$ v(r_2) = v_0 + \int_{r_1}^{r_2} a(r') dr' - \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{GM}{r'^2} dr' $$
$$ v(r_2) = v_0 + \frac{RLA \sin^2 \theta}{2 \pi m c} \left( \frac{1}{r_1} - \frac{1}{r_2} \right) - GM \left( \frac{1}{r_1} - \frac{1}{r_2} \right)$$
screenshot
Where:

$F$ is the thrust
$R$ is the fraction of incident light
$r$ is the distance from the Sun in astronomical units
$S$ is the solar flux in W/m2
$c$ is the speed of light
$A$ is the sail area in m2
$\theta$ is the sail tilt angle

and $r_1 < r_2$.
I tried doing some calculations because I wanted to determine the speed of a solar sail.
I will present the formula I used in the calculation.
The formula at the top refers to　Space Mission Engineering: The new SMAD, page 555, section 18.7.2
What I would like to ask you is whether my formula is correct. I couldn't find any certainty no matter which website I visited.
Sorry for any problems with English; I'm not a native speaker.

I've converted your screenshot to our standard MathJax.

Solar flux $S(r)$ has the wrong units. No $c$ belongs into that formula (assuming that $L$ is the luminosity of the Sun in Watts).

Your formula is wrong. It doesn't even have the right dimensions. For example, $\frac{GM}{r_1}$ has the dimension of speed squared, not speed.
You need to take into account that:

Velocity is the integral of acceleration over time, not path.

Unless you consider the situation where the spacecraft moves directly away from the Sun (or directly towards the Sun) and the sail points directly away from the Sun, then spacecraft's velocity, acceleration due to gravity, and acceleration due to the sail are vectors pointing in different directions, and these directions change with time. You cannot just treat these values as scalars.



Thank you for your comment. I'll convert my formula and re-post. Please tell me whether my new formula is correct or not.

How can I amend this formula? I would be happy if you could answer

@PAUL I don't know if there is a formula for the general situation. You may need to integrate the equations of motion numerically.

I see. Do you think we can simulate this situation in Python by analyzing it numerically?

@PAUL that is an excellent strategy, and simulating trajectories years ago taught me a lot about both Python and spaceflight/orbital mechanics. The key though is to start simple. Don't begin with a complicated example and expect to get the right answer, and don't start with a simulation where you don't know the right answer and therefore can't tell if it worked or not. So for example, can you get the Earth to orbit the Sun and return to its starting point within a few hundred meters in one year?

Can you use a simple atmosphere model and get a satellite to orbit a few times at 200 km, but deorbit immediately at 100 km? Once these things work for you, only then can you move on to more complicated situations with some chance of success.
